# Event for PR update in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

Which event is triggered with I add new commits to a PR in Github actions? I have already tried the `created` and `edited` events. Here's a snippet from my actions file

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
    types:
      - opened
      - edited
  pull_request_review:
    branches:
      - develop
    types:
      - edited
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [**`synchronized`** event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent).

While it is true that "Events API timelines don't include pull request events with the synchronize action.", it is still used with [PR GitHub Actions](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#pull-requests).

For instance: [`seferov/pr-lint-action`](https://github.com/seferov/pr-lint-action/blob/master/.github/workflows/pr-lint.yml).